# please transcribe what the person said in the audio clip

Tags: vocabulary

https://clyp.it/inu52byq
1등 재가 너무 ___

I transcribed what I could catch.

Comment: Again, it would be kind of you if you could edit to add just a little more context - where the snippet is from, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Transcript:
... 인지도도 있으니까 그냥 다니엘 형에게 1등이 주어진다면 저 너무, 제가 고마울 거 같애요.

Translated: If Daniel is given first place, then I will be really thankful.

This is from Produce 101 I guess.